# Falling balls at same time

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have a python tkinter canvas.
I want to draw and let fall multiple balls at the same time.
I need to do it through class.

This is my code so far:

```
import tkinter as tk
from random import randint
from time import sleep


class Circle:
    def __init__(self, canvas):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.canvas_h = canvas.winfo_reqheight()
        self.w = randint(50,300)
        self.x = randint(0, self.canvas_h - self.w)
        self.y = 0
        self.ball = c.create_oval(self.x, -self.w, self.x + self.w, 0,
                                    fill= ['black','red','blue','lime','yellow','grey'][randint(0,5)])
        self.step = randint(5,20)
    
    def fall(self):
        for _ in range((self.canvas_h) // self.step + self.w // self.step):
            self.canvas.move(self.ball, 0 , self.step)
            self.canvas.update()
            sleep(0.02)

        self.canvas.delete(self.ball)

c = tk.Canvas(width=1000, height=1000)
c.pack()
   
count = 10
for ball in [Circle(c) for _ in range(count)]:
    ball.fall()

c.mainloop()
```

It creates multiple balls without a problem.
The problem is that the fall one after one not at same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `.after()` instead of for loop, then the balls will fall at round the same time:

```py
class Circle:
    ...

    def fall(self, i=0):
        if i < ((self.canvas_h+self.w)//self.step):
            self.canvas.move(self.ball, 0 , self.step)
            self.canvas.after(20, self.fall, i+1)
        else:
            self.canvas.delete(self.ball)
```